# Destroy model instance with all dependances in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models with one-to-many connection. Let it be, for example, `User` ans `UserComment` models. When I'm calling `User::destroy` method, I also want to destroy each `UserComment` instance with `user_id` field equal to `id` of destroyed `User`. I may simply overload `User::destroy` method, but I wonder if there is better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way (or more efficient) is to do it through migrations. Let's have a little example with `User` and `UserComment`. Leave user migration as is. For UserComment do:

```
Schema::create('usercomments', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    ....

    $table->foreign('user_id', 'fk_user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade'); //not needed in your case.
});
```

Ok, I haven't used this for a long time, so you may check the syntax online. But that's the gist of it.

When you delete a user, all his comments will be delete as well automatically, by your DB.

Goodluck mate!

Comment: Am I understand right that migrations are capable of setting MySQL stored procedures? This looks amazeing! I'll check it out, thank you.

Comment: Googled about it. This is not a stored procedure, but just MySQL foreign key implementation. Anyway, thanks for filling out my SQL knowledge gap.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the database for this (as suggested above by EddyTheDove), but IF you don't want to use the database for this... you can add something to the deleting event of the User model.

EXAMPLE:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($user) {
         $user->user_comments()->delete();
    });
}
```